# Extracting LiDAR ground points within radius from XY position using Python?

Tags: python, extract, geopandas, lidar

I have ground LiDAR point cloud from a single scan. I imported the point cloud (.las file) and created GeoPandas dataframe including XY coordinates for each point. Can someone please give me guidelines on extracting points within 20 meters radius from the scan position (X = 0, Y = 0) using Python 3x.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [PDAL](https://pdal.io) and developing a [pipeline](https://pdal.io/pipeline.html) to implement your workflow. You can easily [install PDAL via Conda](https://pdal.io/download.html#conda).

With PDAL you can [crop](https://pdal.io/stages/filters.crop.html#filters-crop) to retain points within a 2D or 3D radius of a specified point (using `distance` and `point` options respectively). PDAL also has ground filters like [SMRF](https://pdal.io/stages/filters.smrf.html) and [PMF](https://pdal.io/stages/filters.pmf.html).

I imagine the *basic* pipeline you are going for is something like this, though you may need to adapt it to your data or set some advanced options.

```
{
    "pipeline":[
        {
            "type":"filters.crop",
            "point":"POINT (0 0)",
            "distance":20.0
        },
        {
            "type":"filters.smrf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you've installed PDAL and figured out what your processing pipeline needs to look like, you can [execute it](https://pdal.io/python.html#extend) within Python too, the end result being a Numpy array.

**UPDATE**

The suggested usage of the SMRF filter classifies points, but does not extract them. You'll either need to use a PDAL or Python to extract ground returns by checking pointwise `Classification` values, where a value of 2 indicates a ground return.

**UPDATE**

The previously stated example, shown in Python, as discussed in the comments.

```
import pdal

json = """{
    "pipeline":[
        "/path/to/input.laz",
        {
            "type":"filters.crop",
            "point":"POINT (0 0)",
            "distance":20.0
        },
        {
            "type":"filters.smrf"
        },
        "/path/to/output.laz"
    ]
}"""

pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
pipeline.validate()
pipeline.execute()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @chambbj. I should mention that I have only one return TLS (Topcon) data. I tried to run the code you suggested like below:

   {
       "pipeline":[
       "input.las",
   {
                  "type":"filters.crop",
                  "point":"POINT (1000, 2000)",
                  "distance":20.0
                },
     "output.las"
    ]
}

But got en error : "PDAL: JSON pipeline: Unable to parse pipeline:
* Line 3, Column 3
  Bad escape sequence in string
See Line 3, Column 8 for detail."

Comment: Perhaps there is something else going on here @Sher, but one problem at least is that you have written `POINT (1000, 2000)` and not `POINT(1000 2000)` (without the comma).

Comment: Thanks a lot @chambbj. After changing the coordinates, now the code is running, but for some reason no any output file generated. I am using Cloud compare to find center point for this code. One thing I could see in the point cloud coordinates is that they all rounded to 6 places e.g X = 1000.234566 Y = 1000.343243 by the software. Actually, it could be X = 1000.234566xx Y = 1000.343243xxx so that program may not be able to find given center point. Is it possible to round the coordinates to 6 places?

Comment: I doubt your data has that level of precision (presumably micrometers, or greater, as you are suggesting). Rather, CloudCompare likely offset your data when you imported it. If you are using the point picker, then it reports the coordinates in both offset and global space. Try running again with the actual coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @chambbj, I tried and seems like that's not the case. I tried other examples in PDAL website, got the same problem. 
`import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline('\pipeline.json')
pipeline.validate() `. Returns  `RuntimeError: JSON pipeline: Unable to parse pipeline:
* Line 1, Column 1
  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.`

Comment: This appears to be the first example where you have tried passing a path to the JSON file. That won't work. See https://pdal.io/python.html#extend for an example.

Comment: But I tried `json = """
{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "\9A-1B_SCN0001.las"
    },   
    {
      "type":"filters.pmf"
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.las",
      "filename":"\9A-1B_gr.las"
    }
  ]
}"""
import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
pipeline.validate() ` and go the same error: `RuntimeError: JSON pipeline: Unable to parse pipeline:
* Line 6, Column 7
  Bad escape sequence in string
See Line 6, Column 12 for detail.`

Comment: Your pipeline is incorrect though (invalid JSON). Two problems that I see. Your reader stage is missing the `filename` key (it only lists the value). Also, the paths in both the reader and the writer are incorrect--the slash should be reversed (this would indicate that both files live in the root directory).

Comment: Thanks @chambbj. I corrected the code with `json = """
{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename": "/9A-1B_SCN0001.las"
    },   
    {
      "type":"filters.pmf"
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.las",
      "filename":"/9A-1B_gr.las"
    }
  ]
}"""
import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
pipeline.validate() `, now it is running without error, but not creating any output file.

Comment: Is it truly running @Sher? From what I can see, you've created and possibly validated the pipeline. Your final command should print `True` showing that the pipeline is valid, but you still have not executed it. Try also running `pipeline.execute()`.

Comment: Big thanks @chambbj. After adding `pipeline.execute()` now it is running and creating subset as expected.

Comment: @Sher, you should probably accept this answer, as it seems you commented it solved your question?

Comment: @Sher please kindly accept this answer, as it appears we have answered your question in the end.

Comment: @chambbj,  yes, my problem is solved. But I cannot accept the answer cause I don't have enough reputation to vote.